# Bash arithmetic error: "let: =+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=+") + equals"

Tags: bash, shell

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
function print_hello2 {
    echo "hello $1$2"
}
function sum {
    let result=$1+$2
    echo "$1 + $2 equals $result"
}
sum $1 $2
```

Error:

```
./functions2.sh: line 14: let: =+: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "=+") + equals
```

The result should be that I input two values and it outputs the values and the result of the sum.

Comment: Should $1 be an empty string one gets  =+, at least a space would have given a better error message.

Comment: Don't use `let` at all. It's fragile, non-standard, and doesn't do anything the POSIX standard `$((...))` can't do. (`let` also predates the addition of the the arithmetic statement `((result = $1 + $2))`, which is still non-standard, but more flexible in how you can use whitespace).

Comment: you can make it more stable for case arguments missing with *${var:-default}*: *'sum ${1:-0} ${2:-0}'*

Answer (score 1):

your code is just fine! you are executing script without arguments!

```
./myb.sh 3 6
```

output

```
3 + 6 equals 9
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide arguments to your script, other than that it works perfectly:

```
[s@localhost ~]$ bash function2.sh 8 9
8 + 9 equals 17
[s@localhost ~]$ bash function2.sh -1 5
-1 + 5 equals 4
[s@localhost ~]$ bash function2.sh -1 -6
-1 + -6 equals -7
[s@localhost ~]$
```

Also, your function can be shortened like this:

```
function sum {
    #let result=$1+$2    Can be omitted
    echo "$1 + $2 equals $(($1+$2))"
}
```

Comment: Totally, it was my mistake, Thanks a lot for the help